# Unbounded acyclic resolutions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, sheaf-cohomology

Let $\mathscr A$ be a Grothendieck abelian category. Then every object in $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathscr A)$ is quasi-isomorphic to a $K$-injective object [Stacks, Tag [079P](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/079P)]. In particular, for any left exact functor $F \colon \mathscr A \to \mathscr B$ of abelian categories, the derived functor $RF \colon D(\mathscr A) \to D(\mathscr B)$ is everywhere defined.

However, we rarely ever compute $RF(C^\bullet)$ using $K$-injective resolutions. Instead you use spectral sequences (or basically any tool you can get your hands on). While I don't expect methods in complete generality for computing $RF(C^\bullet)$, there is a relatively mild case that I also couldn't figure out:

> **Question.** *If $C^\bullet \in \operatorname{Ch}(\mathscr A)$ is a complex such that $RF(Z^i(C^\bullet)) = RF(B^i(C^\bullet)) = 0$ for all $i$, then is it true that $RF(C^\bullet) = 0$?*

I don't know a name for the condition that $RF(A) = 0$ for $A \in \mathscr A$, but let me say that $A$ is *totally $F$-acyclic* in this case. For instance, if $\mathscr A = \operatorname{Sh}(X)$ for $X = [0,1]$ and $U = [0,1)$, then $\mathbf Z_U$ is totally $F$-acyclic for $F = \Gamma(X,-)$ since $R\Gamma(X,\mathbf Z) \to R\Gamma(X,\mathbf Z_{X\setminus U})$ is an isomorphism (that is, $R\Gamma_c([0,1),\mathbf Z) = 0$).

Note that the hypotheses imply that $C^i$ and $H^i(C^\bullet)$ are totally $F$-acyclic as well, via the short exact sequences
\begin{align*}
0 \to Z^i \to\ \!& C^i \to B^{i+1} \to 0, \\
0 \to B^i \to\ \!& Z^i \to H^i\ \to 0.
\end{align*}
The case I am most interested in is $\mathscr A = \operatorname{Sh}(X)$ on some reasonable site (e.g. a locally compact Hausdorff space) and $F = \Gamma(X,-)$. As suggested in Jeremy Rickard's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436576/82179), we should at least assume that $\mathscr B$ has exact (countable) products and $F$ preserves (countable) products (these hypotheses also feature in [Tag [08U1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08U1)]).

**Example.** If $C^\bullet$ is *bounded below*, then [Stacks, Tag [015W](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/015W)] gives spectral sequences
\begin{align*}
E_1^{p,q} &= R^qF(C^p) & \Rightarrow R^{p+q}F(C^\bullet)\\
E_2^{p,q} &= R^pF(H^p(C^\bullet))\hspace{-1.8em} & \Rightarrow R^{p+q}F(C^\bullet)
\end{align*}
using the filtrations $F^pC^\bullet = \sigma_{\geq p}C^\bullet$ and $F^pC^\bullet = \tau_{\leq -p}C^\bullet$ respectively (in the latter case there is a re-indexing – see [Stacks, Tag [0FLJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FLJ)] for details when $F = \Gamma(X,-)$ for sheaves on a topological space $X$). Both spectral sequences vanish on their first page, so the result follows from convergence of these spectral sequences. In particular, we may assume $C^\bullet$ is bounded above by the short exact sequence $0 \to \sigma_{\geq 1}C^\bullet \to C^\bullet \to \sigma_{\leq 0} C^\bullet \to 0$ and the result for $\sigma_{\geq 1} C^\bullet$.

The general version of this spectral sequence argument [Stacks, Tag [0BK5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BK5) or [0BKK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BKK)] assumes that you already know that $RF^n(F^p C^\bullet) = 0$ for $p \gg 0$ and $RF^n(F^p C^\bullet) \stackrel\sim\to RF^n(C^\bullet)$ for $p \ll 0$, which you usually only verify by using filtrations that are bounded on one side. In my situation, you cannot verify these hypotheses if you don't already know vanishing of $RF^n(\sigma_{\leq p-1} C^\bullet)$ for $p \ll 0$ (for the first filtration) or of $RF^n(\tau_{\leq -p} C^\bullet)$ for $p \gg 0$ (for the second one). This is another instance of the question we started with!

However, the result does follow if you also know that $C^\bullet \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\operatorname{holim}} \tau_{\geq -n} C^\bullet$ is an equivalence, since the hypothesis on $C^\bullet$ is preserved on $\tau_{\geq -n} C^\bullet$ and $RF$ preserves homotopy limits since it preserves countable products [Stacks, Tag [08U1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08U1)]. But in general, I don't see a reason why this should hold if we merely assume total $F$-acyclicity.

**Remark.** In the bounded below case, it is enough to assume that all $C^i$ are totally $F$-acyclic, by the first of the spectral sequences above. This is not true in the unbounded case: if $Q = [0,1]^{\mathbf N}$ is the Hilbert cube with opens
\begin{align*}
U_i = (0,1)^{\mathbf N_{<i}} \times [0,1) \times [0,1]^{\mathbf N_{>i}},\\
V_i = (0,1)^{\mathbf N_{<i}} \times (0,1] \times [0,1]^{\mathbf N_{> i}},
\end{align*}
then $Q = U_0 \cup V_0$ and $U_i \cap V_i = U_{i+1} \cup V_{i+1}$ for all $i$, leading to a resolution $C^{-i} = \mathbf Z_{U_i} \oplus \mathbf Z_{V_i}$ of $\mathbf Z$. All $R\Gamma(Q,\mathbf Z_{U_i}) = R\Gamma_c(U_i,\mathbf Z)$ vanish, and likewise for $V_i$, but $R\Gamma(Q,C^\bullet) = R\Gamma(Q,\mathbf Z) = \mathbf Z[0]$. See also [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436459/82179) where this resolution plays a role.

I don't know a similar example if we only assume that all $H^i(C^\bullet)$ are totally $F$-acyclic, so that could be another (strictly harder) question.

---

**References.**

[Spalt]  N. Spaltenstein, [*Resolutions of unbounded complexes*](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1988__65_2_121_0). Compos. Math. **65**.2, p. 121-154 (1988).

[Stacks] [The Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu).

Comment: My question is close to part (2) of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/107405/82179), but made more precise. The other question never received a very satisfying answer.

Comment: Your notion of $F$-acyclicity is a little too strong it seems: since $F$ is left exact, we have $H^0(RF(T))=T$ for any $T$ in $\mathcal A$. Your definition of acyclicity seems to say that the complex $C$ is actually zero in each degree! We should define acyclicity of $T$ by saying $H^i(RF(T))=0$ for $i\neq 0$. Then we might want to know if $F(C)\simeq RF(C)$ whenever $Z^i(C)$ and $B^i(C)$ are $F$-acyclic for all $i$.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski what I wrote is actually the condition that I mean, but you're right that the classical notion of $F$-acyclicity means $RF(T) = F(T)$. If $C^\bullet$ is a bounded below complex of $F$-acyclic objects in that sense, you don't get $RF(C^\bullet) = 0$ but $RF(C^\bullet) = F(C^\bullet)$. So I should have chosen a different name (totally $F$-acyclic?). I have rewritten the question with this improved terminology. But your version also sounds like a sensible question, and maybe more analogous to the classical story of $F$-acyclic resolutions. My question is a baby case of that.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something... Do you not know that the map to the homotopy limit of the truncations is an isomorphism in the setting that you're interested in (of a Grothendieck abelian category)? (I guess I'm suggesting that you already solved the question)

Comment: @NikolasKuhn oh do I? I am aware of results in AB4* categories [Bökstedt–Neeman, Rmk. 2.3], but that doesn't apply here. There are results in the Stacks project (essentially due to Spaltenstein) under some technical hypotheses \[Tag [0D62](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0D62) and its corollaries\], which apply in the [other answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436459/82179) I gave. But I am wondering if I can remove these conditions when the $Z^i$ and $B^i$ are totally $F$-acyclic.

Comment: It seems like this is shown in the proof of existence of K-injective resolutions \[Stacks, Tag [090Y](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/090Y)\].

Comment: @NikolasKuhn That proof assumes exact countable products, which isn't the case for a general Grothendieck category.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid this is not very close to the case that you say you're most interested in ... maybe you want $F$ to preserve products?

But let $A=k[x]/(x^2)$, and let $\mathscr{A}$ be the category $\operatorname{Mod}A$ of $A$-modules. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the Serre subcategory of finitely generated modules, $\mathscr{A}/\mathscr{F}$ the quotient category, and $F:\mathscr{A}\to\operatorname{Mod}k$ the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{A}/\mathscr{F}}(V,-)$, where $V$ is an infinite direct sum of copies of $A/Ax$.

Let $C^\bullet$ be the complex with $A/Ax$ in every degree, and zero differentials. Then $Z^i(C^\bullet)$ and $B^i(C^\bullet)$ have injective resolutions by objects of $\mathscr{F}$ for all $i$, and are therefore "totally $F$-acyclic".

But $C^\bullet$ has a $K$-injective resolution $J^\bullet$ that is the product of all the shifts $\{I^\bullet[t]\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ of a minimal injective resolution $I^\bullet$ of $A/Ax$, and $F(J^\bullet)$ has zero differentials, but is nonzero in every degree, so $RF(C^\bullet)\neq0$

Comment: Thanks for this example! My understanding here is that because $\mathbf{Mod}_A$ is AB4*, every complex $C^\bullet$ is the derived limit of its truncations $\tau_{\geq -p} C^\bullet$, so what goes wrong here is indeed preservation of (countable) products under $F$. But at the very least, the example shows that any positive result cannot be completely formal ― this is already a break with the bounded below case where no hypothesis is needed.

Comment: I have now added the hypothesis that $F$ preserves products, like you suggested. There was already a hint of this hypothesis in the holim argument in my question. (Surely we can't "French trick" our way out of this by adding extra hypotheses until the statement becomes tautological?)

Comment: P.S. I got a downvote on the question after the last edit (without a comment explaining, as usual). Do you think I should ask a different question instead with the extra hypothesis, given that your answer technically addresses the question as asked?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I think I have an answer to the question with the added hypotheses, which I will edit into my previous answer if it survives the writing process, in which case the question in your comment is probably moot.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I think the proof that I've added shows that the extra hypotheses are sufficient.

Comment: Could you explain the statements about why the truncations are the homotopy limits of their further truncations?

Comment: @NikolasKuhn Hmm, I thought I had a reason, but now I'm not so sure. I'll roll back to the previous version while I think about it.